# Apache VirtualHost - Make subdomain go to same place

Tags: apache-2.2, domain-name-system, virtualhost

I have a domain like 0.ape.stream.local

The 0 increments up to an infinite number.

How do I go about making any number (*.ape.stream.local) go to same place?

Answer (score 2):

```
ServerAlias *.ape.stream.local
```

Answer (score 1):

You pretty much have the answer in your post. You are looking to setup a "wildcard" which will point any (*) subdomain to the same location.

You will need to set this up on the DNS level along with the web server level.

For DNS simply point *.ape.stream.local -> webserverip or cluster ip

At the Webserver depending on which flavor you are using (Apache or IIS) you can either setup a wildcard subdomain to serve the traffic or you can setup individual configurations for each subdomain depending on your needs.

Comment: I can't seem to get it to work. Can you paste like a full solution?

Comment: At which level are you having issues getting the configuration to work? The DNS level or the Apache level?

Comment: stream.local works fine

Comment: 0.ape.stream.local works fine

Comment: which have been configured in the hosts file of Ubuntu
I just need *.ape.stream.local to go to same place now

Comment: Oh and I'm doing it through Apache's httpd.conf

Comment: You will need to add this bit to the config: ServerAlias *.ape.stream.local which will allow apache to listen for any subdomain.

Comment: I've tried that but it doesn't seem to work :/

Comment: The domain has changed since I posted this question but here's what I have:

Comment: `<VirtualHost *:80>

 ServerName network.local       

 ServerAlias *.stream.network.local 

 UseCanonicalName Off

 DocumentRoot "/var/www"
       
</VirtualHost>`

Comment: That configuration is correct it sounds likely you are still having issues with DNS though. The reason the two domains work that you described above is because they are in the local host file. You have to setup your DNS to point the wildcard domain to the webserver's IP in order for your configuration to work

Comment: How do I do this?

Comment: It depends on which level you want to set the DNS at. You can add this in your local host, at the domain level or at your provider for public DNS.

Comment: I'm just using this server locally for development

Comment: If this server is in a domain then you need to set the DNS entry at the domain level. If not you just need to input the wildcard entry in the local host file of the machine you use to access this server.

Comment: In my host file I do have 127.0.0.1 network.local

Comment: It should be with the wildcard in your example 127.0.0.1 *.network.local

Comment: Nope; that's not working :/

Comment: Your entry in your host file should appear as: 127.0.0.1 network.local *.network.local

Comment: Nope; that ain't working D: :S